# How To Apply Mongoose Validations In My Update Profile Api

Tags: node.js, api, express, validation, mongoose

***Here Is My Schema***

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");`

`const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({`

`name: {`
`type: String,`
`required: "this field is required",`
`validate: {`
`validator: function (v) {`
`return /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z -]+[a-zA-Z]$/.test(v); //validate name with regex.`
`},`
`message: props => ${props.value} is not a valid Name!`
`},`
`},`
`email: {`
`type: String,`
`required: "this field is required",`
`validate: {`
`validator: function (v) {`
`return /^\w+([.-]?\w+)`*`@\w+([.-]?\w+)`*`(.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v); //validate email with regex.`
`},`
`message: props => ${props.value} is not a valid Email!`
`},`
`},`
`mobile: {`
`type: String,`
`required: "this field is required",`
`validate: {`
`validator: function (v) {`
`return /^(+\d{1,2}\s?)?1?-?.?\s?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/.test(v); //validate mobile number with regex.`
`},`
`message: props => ${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
`},`
`},`
`image: {`
`type: String,`
`validate: {`
`validator: function (v) {`
`return /.(jpe?g|png)$/i.test(v); //Validate IMAGE With Regex.`
`},`
`message: props => ${props.value} is not a valid File type of Image!`
`}`
`},`
`password: {`
`type: String,`
`min: [6, 'Password Is Too Short.'],`
`},`
`confirmpassword: {`
`type: String`
`},`
`companyname: {`
`type: String`
`},`
`is_admin: {`
`type: Number,`
`},`
`is_verified: {`
`type: Number,`
`default: 0`
`},`
`token: {`
`type: String,`
`default: ''`
`}`
`}); //User Schema With validation`

`` module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` ``

***Here is my Routes***

`admin_route.get('/edit-user', auth.isLogin, adminController.edituserLoad);`

`admin_route.post('/edit-user',upload.single('image'), auth.isLogin, adminController.updateUser);`

***Here Is my Controllers***

`const edituserLoad = async (req, res) => {`
`try {`

```
    const id = req.query.id;
    const userData = await User.findById({ _id: id });
    if (userData) {

        res.render('edit-user', { user: userData });

    } else {

        res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');

    }

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

`}`

`const updateUser = async (req, res) => {`
`try {`

```
    const id = req.body.id;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const mobile = req.body.mobile;
    const companyname = req.body.companyname;
    const is_verified = req.body.verify;
    const image = req.file.filename;

    const userData = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: { name: name, email: email, mobile: mobile, companyname: companyname, is_verified: is_verified, image: image} });

    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

`}`

***Here Is my Ejs***

```
`<% include('../layouts/header.ejs') %>`

        <h1>Edit User</h1>

        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Enter Name" value="<%= user.name %>">
            <br><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter Email" value="<%= user.email %>">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile" value="<%= user.mobile %>">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="companyname" placeholder="Enter CompanyName (Optional)"
                value="<%= user.companyname %>">
            <br><br>
            <label> Verified </label>
            <input type="radio" name="verify" value="1" <% if (user.is_verified==1) { %> checked <% } %>>
            <nbsp></nbsp>
            <label> Unverified </label>
            <input type="radio" name="verify" value="0" <% if (user.is_verified==0) { %> checked <% } %>>
            <br><br>
            <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Profile Picture">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= user._id %>">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Update User">

        </form>
        <br><br>
        <a href="/admin/dashboard">DashBoard</a>

        <% include('../layouts/footer.ejs') %>
```

Please Tell Me How Add Validations In My Update Profile Api??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mention code can be helpful.

```
const schema = new Schema({


name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
const Cat = db.model('Cat', schema);

// This cat has no name :(
const cat = new Cat();

let error;
try {
  await cat.save();
} catch (err) {
  error = err;
}
    
assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
  'Path `name` is required.');

error = cat.validateSync();
assert.equal(error.errors['name'].message,
  'Path `name` is required.');
```

For required key in schema, you have to pass boolean and not a string message.

But in case you have to pass string, use below mentioned syntax.

```
required: [true, 'Why no bacon?']
```

for validate, refer below mentioned code.

```
validate: {
  validator: function(v) {
    return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
  },
  message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
},
```